# PostBack+Googlemap

Tags: map

Всем привет!
Вопрос:
на странице отображается google map, при ее перетягивании туда-сюда через Ajax грузятся данные, в том числе формируются ссылки на другую страницу сайта. Так вот если перейти по ссылки, а потом вернуться назад (кнопочку в браузере НАЗАД нажать), то все опять грузится заново - т.е. все становится на первоначальный вид, а нужно чтобы остались прежние результаты - карта на прежнем месте куда ее перетянули. 
Подскажите пожалуйста...

Comment: Неужели никто не знает????

Comment: На ASP.net это делалось так: if (!ISPostBack) {} else {}.... Как на php это реализовать??? или нужно js использовать????